# Uploading image file using html and javascript returning fakepath

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I am trying to upload image on my website to add it to the database as base64 encoded string. The problem is I can not receive the file path to upload it by java. On the front-end I am using HTML and javascript, here is the HTML tag:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>passport image </label><input id="image-input" type="file"
                        placeholder="file">
    </div>
```

in javascript I added:

```
document.getElementById("image-input").value;
```

The path of the image that arrives to me is 'C:\fakepath\IMAGE_NAME'.
 I need a way to send the photo or it's path to the java code, how can I do this while I am not using jsf nor spring.

Comment: What have you tried in Java?

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: This is a security measure, modern browsers do not disclose the original location of the file on the client any more, but substitute it with this fake entry. You still get the original file name though.

Comment: I know that @JackBashford . I am using javascript to parse the form parameters to java servlet by ajax query but I don't know how to parse file instead of a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some browsers have a security feature that prevents JavaScript from
>   knowing your file's local full path. It makes sense - as a client, you
>   don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem.
>
> I use the object FileReader on the input onchange event for your input
>   file type! This example uses the readAsDataURL function and for that
>   reason you should have an tag. The FileReader object also has
>   readAsBinaryString to get the binary data, which can later be used to
>   create the same file on your server

Example:

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputFile");
var fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
fReader.onloadend = function(event){
    var img = document.getElementById("yourImgTag");
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is helpful, but this will display the image on the page, while I want to pass it via html input to the servlet. Can you please help in this?

Comment: Yeah this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm should help you. Let me know it this gets you what you need.

Comment: This answer is what I need. I didn't notice from the beginning when using the function readAsDataURL the source will be converted to encoded image, and that what I need to save in the database.

Answer (score 0):

**try this !** using : replace

```
var imgpath = document.getElementById("image-input").value;
var newPath = imgpath .replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")
```